# Linear regression implementation from scratch

Tags: python, linear-regression

I'm trying to understand the gradient descent algorithm.

Can someone please explain why I'm getting high MSE values using the following code, or if I missed some concept can you please clarify?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

my_data = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.arange(0,100),
                       'y': np.arange(0,100)})
X = my_data.iloc[:,0:1].values
y = my_data.iloc[:,1].values

def gradientDescent(X, y, lr = 0.001, n = 1000):

    n_samples, n_features = X.shape
    cost = []
    weight = np.zeros([n_features])
    b = 0

    for _ in range(n):
        # predict
        y_hat = np.dot(X, weight) + b # y = ax + b

        residual =  y - y_hat
        db = -(2/n_samples) * np.sum(residual)
        dw = -(2/n_samples) * np.sum(X.T * residual, axis = 1)

        # update weights

        weight -= (lr * dw)
        b -= (lr * db)

        cost.append(((y-y_hat) **2).mean())

    return weight, b, cost

gradientDescent(X,y)
```

Comment: have you tried with different lr?

Comment: Simple gradient descent is like climbing down a mountain in the fog: because of the fog you can only see near your feet, so you look near your feet to see which direction goes down. You then move in that direction, and look again. If the mountainside is fairly smooth this can work well, but if the mountainside is rough you can get stuck in a low spot. Success can also depend on where you start. In this analogy the initial parameters are your starting point, the direction at your feet is the local gradient, and learning rate is how far you travel before looking near your feet again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert, but I think you are currently experiencing the `exploding gradient` problem. If you step through your code you will notice that your weight value is swinging from positive to negative in increasing steps. I believe you cannot find the minimum because using mse for this dataset is causing you to jump back and forth never converging. Your x and y ranges to 100, so when you look at the cost it is just blowing up.

If you want to use mse with your current x and y values you should normalize your data. You can do this by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation, or just normalize both x and y to 1.

For example:

```
my_data.x = my_data.x.transform(lambda x: x / x.max())
my_data.y = my_data.y.transform(lambda x: x / x.max())
```

If you do this you should see your cost converge to ~0 with enough iterations.